# Get element with attached event binding in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to get the element with the `(click)` event binding:

```
<th class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text ui-sortable-column" (click)="reorderComponents($event)">
  <span class="ui-column-title">Component Name</span>
  <span class="ui-sortable-column-icon fa fa-fw fa-sort {{compSortIcon}}"></span>
</th>
```

As you can see, it is the `<th>` element. However, after clicking and logging the event object, it shows this:

[image]

[image]

I want to get the `<th>` element, but sadly I couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Why do you want `<th>`?

Comment: @Satpal I want to add an attribute to `<th>`, so it's necessary for me to get that specific element when clicked.

Comment: I guess you want to use angular as jquery. Angular is different. If you want to work with html elements use directives.

Comment: try to log event.currentTarget

Comment: Its value is null.

Comment: `event.currentTarget.nodeName` should work for you. You did something wrong

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/PpfCI0zx25ECdtfJsLmu?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

```
reorderComponents(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
}
```

It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/HoY6lqGEZwdJvKDKAFie?p=preview)**

Comment: That actually worked. It's weird because when I logged the event object, the `currentTarget` is null, but when logging the `event.currentTarget`, it shows the `<th>` element. I don't really know why but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you.

```
reorderComponents(event){
   console.log(event.toElement.nodeName)
}
```